# setting up ringtone ringing time in android

Tags: android, ringtone

I am developing an Android app with ringtone setup. The problem is that I want to set my ringtone to 8 seconds. Here is my code:

```
 Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
 mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alert);
 final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
      mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
      mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
      mMediaPlayer.prepare();
      mMediaPlayer.start();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I am using Timer to stop the Ringtone.

```
long ringDelay = 3500;
Uri notification =RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
final Ringtone alarmRingtone= RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
alarmRingtone.play();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
    alarmRingtone.stop();
}
};
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(task, ringDelay);
```